# Boot error: "Failed to start network time synchronization"

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

When I boot ubuntu then it shows error

[Failed] : "Failed to start network time synchronization"
See 'Systemct1 status systemd-timesyncd.services' for details

Comment: Case matters! The command YOU should type is `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.services` - Not a capital `S`, letter "ell" (`l`) not `1`.

Comment: I didn't command anything. When I started ubuntu then I got this error.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! The output of `timedatectl` might be useful here.

Comment: I think what waltinator is trying to say [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062110/boot-error-failed-to-start-network-time-synchronization#comment1738804_1062110) is that if you were to [edit] the output of `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service` into your post it would be useful in helping us solve your problem. Thank you for helping us help you!